# How to call a normal function inside a class method

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a normal function **show_slider_form_input()** inside `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'admin/partials/absb_bt_to_s-admin-display.php'`. Here is the complete code on absb_bt_to_s-admin-display.php:

```
<style type="text/css">
.clearfix:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
</style>
<?php 

function show_slider_form_input(){?>
<div class="row form-group clearfix" >
    <div style="width: 20%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">
        Image : <input type="file" name="image[]"  />
    </div>  
    <div style="width: 27%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">
        Title : <input type="text" name="title[]" />
    </div>

    <div style="width: 22%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">
        More Info : <input type="text" name="more_info[]" />
    </div>

    <div style="width: 22%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">
        Button : <input placeholder="Put the url.." type="text" name="button_link[]" />
    </div>
    <div style="width: 5%; float: left; ">
        <input type="button" class="button button-primar add_more"  value="+" />
    </div>
</div>

<?php }
```

Now I am calling this function inside a method named new_slider_html of **class Absb_bt_to_s {}** as follows:

```
public function new_slider_html(){
    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'admin/partials/absb_bt_to_s-admin-display.php');
    if( !check_ajax_referer( 'absbBtToS-nonce', 'security' ) ){
        wp_send_json_error('error!');
    }
    show_slider_form_input(); 
}
```

But I am getting 500 error. when I remove **show_slider_form_input();** everything looks good. It seems to me that this function is calling from function which is inside a class. But how to figure out this issue. Any idea?

Comment: the problem is _where_ you include that file/function. cannot be inside the method. If you include this file outside class-declaration it might work, but this would be bad design anyway..

Comment: Can you copy-paste one of the 500 errors you got please?

Comment: Have you try to echo the results of the function?

Comment: Yes. I tried. Modify the function definition and return the html and echoing it.

Comment: Check the `php_errors.log` file (this is the default name of the error log, you can find it's actual path in `php.ini`, the [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) value). The cause of the error is reported there (most probably the function doesn't exist because the `include` statement fails).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is register your function on early stage `plugins_init` or `init` wp hook, or add `function_exists` before running your predefined function.

P.S.
So you including html (css code), which also happen contain your function. Then when it fails you trying to output json? I guess you need to check your logic again.

My best suggest is to remove function wrapper from your include file and change calling function

```
public function new_slider_html(){
    if( !check_ajax_referer( 'absbBtToS-nonce', 'security' ) ){
        wp_send_json_error('error!');
    }
    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'admin/partials/absb_bt_to_s-admin-display.php'); 
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this code should be either in a core plugin file or in the theme's functions.php file....